# Error while installing pytest. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, installation, pytest

Im trying to install pytest on my MAC with Big Sur OS. I currently have both python 2.7 and python 3.9, but python 2.7 is a default installation.
When I run the command:

```
% pip install -U pytest
```

Getting an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-lQw0PM-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyparsing-2.0.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

How should I fix it, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

May be you should trying creating [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and try installing pytest in it.

or

This may be an pip conflict between python 2.7 & 3.9, so you can run

```
 python3.9 -m pip install pytest
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thank you!

I tried first % python3.9.5 -m pip install pytest

But it responded zsh: command not found: python3.9.5

So I used  ~ % python3.9 -m pip install pytest 

And got 
Successfully installed attrs-21.2.0 iniconfig-1.1.1 packaging-20.9 pluggy-0.13.1 py-1.10.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytest-6.2.4 toml-0.10.2